# Any way to use the timeline markers as input list?

Tags: python, animation-nodes

Basically, I have a phrase and want to add a letter every time a marker is met.

*i.e. every time a letter is hit while writing a message.*

Is It possible to do something like this using the animation nodes?

I found out that the path for them is `bpy.context.scene.timeline_markers` but don't know how to mix the things together.. ^^"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we should get the frames at which the markers are set, to do this, we can use this list comprehension:

```
[marker.frame for marker in bpy.context.scene.timeline_markers]
```

Which returns the frames at which the markers were set:

[image: Expression]

Next, I am going to subtract the current frame from this list, now all the markers that have frame values less than the current frame will have negative values. If I max the output with zero, all the values that were negative will become zero. If I "not" (Invert) the result, all zeros becomes ones and non zeros becomes zeros. If I sum all the values of the output, I will get the number of markers that are before or at the current frame. I can now use this output in a *Trim Text Node* to show the characters:

[image: Node Tree]

Which results in:

[image: Result]